# Retrieve all bit values in byte NodeJS Buffer

Tags: node.js, binary

I have a simple Buffer object and want to read the bit values from it.

```
var buffer = new Buffer([0x16]);
```

In theory it should be 10000110 as the result?

Comment: How do you figure?  You put value 16 in the first byte of a one-byte buffer.  That's 00010000.

Comment: The 16 is hex which is a decimal 22.

Comment: It is not hex unless you create it as `new Buffer([0x16]);`

Comment: Apologies, I meant to type that!

Comment: What's the question here?  How do you get that bit pattern?  Why is it not equivalent to that bit pattern?